# How to checkall/uncheck all elements in a table which is inside form using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Hi I am trying to figure out a way in which the button changes its value and also all the checkboxes gets checked/unchecked on the click of a button.

I also cannot understand how to parse in DOM. 
I have tried something on jsfiddle but unable to materialize it. Can someone help me out in it.

Here is the link.

```
Here is the jQuery code that I have written

> $(document).ready(function(){
>     $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
>         alert('inside toggle function');
>         $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',true);
>         $(this).val('uncheck all')
>     },function(){
>         $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
>         $(this).val('check all');        
>     }) })
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mayankmanu/x6maqrgL/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `toggle()` functionality was deprecated and removed some time ago, at least the version of `toggle()` you're using.

You should be listening for the `change` event, and use the `checked` property to toggle the state of the other checkboxes with jQuery's `prop()`

```
$('.selectall').on('change', function() {
    $('div input').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/FAYJS/338/)

I'm using `on()`, that requires a newer version of jQuery than the one you're using in you're fiddle, you should update the latest version.

### EDIT:

to do it with a button, you need a flag to keep track of the state, and create you're own toggle

```
$('#selectAll').on('click', function () {
    var flag = !$(this).data('flag');

    $('#search_data input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', flag);

    $(this).data('flag', flag);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x6maqrgL/1/)

Comment: I want to do it using a button. I have provided a link to the fiddle. Can you tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Yes it worked, but also need to change the value of the button each click. However, i will work to find it out. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/x6maqrgL/4/)

If at any point there's at least one unchecked checkbox, then you want to check all, otherwise uncheck all. And you want to recalculate whenever any individual checkbox is changed.

```
$('#selectAll').on('click', function(){
    var numUnChecked = $(':checkbox:not(:checked)','#search_data').length;
    $(':checkbox', '#search_data').prop('checked',numUnChecked);
    $(this).val( numUnChecked ? 'uncheck all' : 'check all' );
});
$(':checkbox', '#search_data').on('change', function() {
    var numUnChecked = $(':checkbox:not(:checked)','#search_data').length;
    $('#selectAll').val( numUnChecked ? 'check all' : 'uncheck all' );
});
```